# What's the opposite of crowded, when speaking of roads?

Tags: word-request

I have trouble explaining the crowdness of a road. How can I say if a road is not crowded and you can easily speed up with your car there?

Comment: Maybe your question needs to be more precise. If you mean non-crowded at this time of day (fx not rush hour) expressions like “clear” and “light traffic” is the best choice to capture the meaning. But if you mean a road that in general is non-crowded expressions like “desolate” or “remote” is better I think

Comment: @rabbitco My question is general. I don't even want it to be specifically for roads. I have the same question about other places like hospitals. How can I describe a hospital that is not crowded and all doctors are free to check you out.

Comment: your question is both titled and stated as specifically pertaining to “*roads*”. If you simply need a generic word for various use cases you could just use “*uncrowded*”. But often another word will better capture the intended meaning depending on the context in which it is used.

Comment: The body of the question specifically asked for how to describe a road that is not crowded. You shouldn't assume that in English you can apply the answers to describe, say, the lack of passengers on a bus. Furthermore, the choice of word may depend on the reason for it being not crowded — maybe the usual commuters are gone because it's a weekend, maybe everyone is confined to stay home because of covid. The point is, the question you asked is the question you posed, and you shouldn't change it or generalize it after posting.

Comment: Side note: I wouldn't use "crowded" for roads, since that usually refers to people (not cars). I'd rather use "busy".

Comment: @NotThatGuy: I would regard a "busy" road as one with high flow (many vehicles passing each point per minute) and a "crowded" road as whose spacial density is higher than would be needed for maximum flow, but whose flow rate is less than maximum.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In American English, I would use **empty** or **clear**, but to mean two slightly different things.

I would most often use **empty** to indicate that there is little traffic:

> The roads are empty. Everybody must have decided to stay home today!

I would use **clear** to indicate that there was a problem on the road, such as an accident or traffic jam, and that problem was eliminated.

> The roads are clear. The accident was moved to the side of the road about an hour ago.

or

> Rush hour is over. The roads are clear.

---

Because of all the comments, I want to clarify my response with a reminder that I'm only referring to American English:

(1) I use the word **empty** to indicate "not crowded".  It does not necessarily mean "devoid of people, cars, etc." It's a relative term. For example:

- the roads are empty (very few cars compared to normal)
- the hospital is empty (only a few patients)
- the parking lot is empty (only a few cars)
- the stadium was empty (not crowded)

(2) Yes, I might say "the parking lot is empty" even though it has a few cars in it. It's all about context. For example:

> Not many people went to the concert. We were able to move five rows closer to the stage because the stadium was empty.

(3) You can also qualify empty for emphasis (but you don't have to). For example:

> The parking lot is **pretty empty**. You shouldn't have any trouble finding a space.

> The hospital is **so empty**! I bet there are only 30 patients!

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Can the word "empty" be used in other places that are not crowded e.g. hospitals, parking lots, department stores, etc.? For example if I work downtown and a friend of mine wants to visit me and they're concerning about where to park their car, and there's a parking lot near my workplace which usually is not crowded and I want to recommend it to them, can I say "There's an empty parking lot near my workplace. You can park your car there."?

Comment: Absolutely! I would most often say "the parking lot is empty."

Comment: You can also say "there's one empty parking space left" and refer to a single space even though the parking lot is full. Or, "There's an empty parking space right in front of the house."

Comment: The parking lot is *empty* but the hospital is *not busy*.  The hospital could be described as *empty* if it were devoid of people in general or if there was some context to clarify that you meant *not busy* when you said *empty*.

Comment: Just wanted to point out: If someone says "the roads are empty" I interpret that to mean virtually *nobody* is out driving. That seems stronger than the original question.  The answer below of "open", used as the phrase "open road" or "road is wide open" doesn't mean a complete absence of traffic, but just that there is no traffic that would impede forward progress at any speed in any way. Thus IMHO that would be the preferred answer here.

Comment: I wouldn't use 'Empty' to mean 'not crowded'.  For example, would also use 'Empty' to describe a cup half-full of liquid: no-one would.  Yet you suggest to describe a half-full carpark as 'Empty'. 'Not crowded' is very different from 'Empty'.

Comment: If there was a large parking lot with only a few cars in it, I might say that the parking lot is "pretty empty" instead of "empty," but I would use the word "empty" to indicate not crowded.

Answer (score 25):

I would most often say **traffic was light** or **there wasn't much traffic**.

I might also say **the roads were quiet**

I might even say **the roads were empty** if it was particularly dramatic and unexpected.

Comment: How about the word "clear" which is mentioned in some other answers? You've mentioned the words "quiet" and "empty" but didn't say anything about "clear". Does it show that this word is not used in this kind of situation?

Comment: @MohdSala: English has many synonyms. It would be unreasonable to expect a single answer to list them all.

Comment: @MohdSala As a native speaker, if someone told me the roads were "clear", I would assume that they had previously been blocked to some extent by an accident or some debris, or (in the winter) had been covered in snow/ice. So I would say the roads were "empty" or "fairly/nearly empty" depending on whether there were zero cars or just a small number of cars.

Comment: @MohdSala I agree with Herohtar, "clear" implies free of obstructions or weather conditions, not free of traffic.

Comment: ''The road is clear'' sounds a bit strange to a native speaker.

Comment: Yeah, I think "clear" only makes sense as a contrast to "obstructed", so it needs to be obvious from context what that obstruction is: snow, debris, etc?

Answer (score 12):

You can say the road is clear:

***[Clear](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/it/dizionario/inglese/clear):***

> not covered or blocked by anything:
>
> - *The journey was quite quick because the road was clear (= there was not much traffic on it).*

(Cambridge Dictionary)

Comment: This is not common in American english to refer to light traffic and would usually have the implication of either not having snow/ice or having been blocked by an obstruction that is now cleared up (so to speak).  Is this use of clear more common in other locales?

Comment: @coppereyecat: As a native speaker of American English, I think the term "clear" would imply that the road is free of impediments to traffic flow.  If traffic on a 4-lane freeway is moving at 50ph, I would describe the road as clear whether traffic is dense or sparse, but if traffic on that same road were moving at only 20mph because 80% of motorists wanted to exit onto a two-lane freeway I would not describe the traffic as clear because the back-up from the two-lane freeway was impeding traffic flow on the four-lane road.

Comment: @coppereyecat:      I think the expression is used both in BrE and AmE. Lexico (AmE) at point 3 of clear: “*free of any obstructions or unwanted objects.
‘with a clear road ahead he shifted into high gear’*”

Comment: @supercat it may be regional then, as also a native speaker of American English ;)   Weirdly, it seems to me more likely to be used on a larger road like you describe - maybe because a busy road could often be blocked by traffic jams, etc. I can't imagine using clear to describe an empty country highway. But using it for a busy highway in town seems a lot more plausible to me today than it did yesterday. Language is weird.

Comment: @coppereyecat: The use of the expression for wider roads isn't "weird", since only larger roads could have a large number of vehicles on it without those vehicles being "obstacles".

Answer (score 10):

A road or some terrain can be [**open**:](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/open)

> 7a. : presenting no obstacle to passage or view : : not enclosed, obstructed, or filled with objects
>
> // The open road

In addition to some words others have mentioned, such as **empty** and **sparse**: If a place has no people, we could call it **deserted**.  Too few people, and we might call it **lonely**.

Comment: This is the most used in my experience in the United States Midwest. "The roads were wide open." Other answers such as "clear" we would probably use to refer to the condition of the roads (i.e. are they covered in snow? or have the been plowed [cleared of snow]?) "Empty", I would say is a close second.

Answer (score 6):

Not a native here, but I think you could simply state that the road is [**empty**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/empty) (or **almost empty**):

> not containing any things or **people**
>
> - *an empty house/street*

Alternatively, you could say that the traffic on the road is [**light**](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/whats-the-opposite-of-heavy-traffic.2782663/).

Comment: The emphasis is weird. It makes it look as if the opposite of "crowded" was "people".

Answer (score 5):

Edit: Reordered for most commonly used phrases being near the top

#### Clear roads (very common)

- The roads were **clear(ed)** of ice.
- The roads were **clear(ed)** of cars.
- The roads were **clear**. (Could also work for somehow see-through roads)

#### Light traffic (very common)

- The **traffic was light**. (Do not confuse with the Traffic Light, which is a Traffic Signal!!!)
- There was **light traffic** this morning.

#### Empty roads (very common)

- The roads are **empty**. (The roads don't "contain" vehicles)

#### Deserted (common)

- This road is **deserted**. These roads are **deserted**.
- Remember the meaning of **deserted** by the population of most deserts (areas with almost no rain/snow/precipitation): very small.
- **Deserted** implies there are 0 or *maybe* 1 vehicle(s).

#### Desolate (common)

- This road is **desolate**. (The road gives off empty, lonely, and sad feelings to you)

#### Barren (not as common)

- This road is **barren**. (similar to desert)
- This road is **bare**. (the road is bland, featureless, devoid of noteworthy/important features/landmarks)

#### Dense (uncommon)

- The traffic isn't very **dense**.
- The roads aren't very **dense with traffic**.
- Dense: packed closely together. Dense refers to traffic in the above sentence
- Not using **with traffic** means something completely different: The roads are essentially fluffy.

#### Scarce (uncommon)

- The roads are **scarce with vehicles**.
- The roads are **scarcely populated**.
- *Use **with vehicles** to avoid confusion*, as "The roads are **scarce**" implies there are not many roads close to where you are.

#### Sparse (uncommon)

- The roads are **sparse with vehicles**.
- The roads are **sparsely populated**.
- *Use **with vehicles** to avoid confusion*, as "The roads are **sparse**" implies there are not many roads close to where you are.
- Notice how Sparse and Scarce used identically.

Comment: I'm not sure I've ever heard the phrase "sparse with..." before. Perhaps "Traffic was sparse" or in other contexts "cover sparsely with..."

Comment: To be clear, "deserted" doesn't mean "like a desert", although that might be a useful mnemonic. It actually means "without people" or "abandoned".

Comment: Similar to what @Jontia said for "sparse with", it seems more natural to say "Traffic isn't very dense". If you said "The roads aren't very dense", I'd think you meant the roads themselves, not traffic.

Comment: It seems like you looked up a thesaurus and then tried to justify the results. *Scarce* and *sparse* are inappropriate to describe traffic on roads. *Bare* means something else altogether — it is usually used to describe a road that is free of ice or snow.

Comment: I just put what I have personally used and heard as a native English speaker, though I did look up most of the words just to double check they weren't pure slang

Comment: You've heard people say "The roads are sparse with vehicles"?  I could easily image "vehicles were sparse", but that first construction looks plain wrong.  Some of these examples are good and common, but they're mixed in with very odd usages.  At least you did mark them common vs. uncommon, but some of the usages you cite go beyond uncommon, IMO.  Also, as discussed in other answers and comments, "clear" is primarily about weather, or removal of a previous obstruction, not just traffic.  You could consider a traffic *jam* to be an obstruction that's now clear, if cars were fully stopped before

Comment: @PeterCordes: I've heard "traffic was sparse", to refer a a condition more extreme than "light".  If traffic is light, one expects that one's travel times would be the same as if it were non-existent.  If it's "sparse", one would be likely to go significant periods of time without seeing any other vehicles at all.

Comment: @supercat: Yeah, "x was/were sparse" is totally normal usage.  But "sparse **with**" is what I, Jontia, and wjandrea are objecting to (see earlier comments).

Answer (score 0):

I would say that the road was desolate.

[desolate](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/desolate):

> devoid of inhabitants and visitors : DESERTED

(From Merriam-Webster dictionary)

Comment: In connection to roads, my brain jumps to meaning 3a), "showing the effects of abandonment and neglect" for "desolate"

Comment: Desolate is far too literary to use in such a context.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the word "**scarce**" if we are talking about the population density in a region  not being very high for a particular commodity or species.

So in your case, the situation is the scarcity of traffic on the streets. A sentence to back this up might be,

"The traffic is scarce on Street 101 due to the city being in a lockdown."

Comment: To be clear, you would use it like "**traffic** is scarce". Saying "the **road** is scarce" doesn't really mean anything, and "**roads** are scarce" means there aren't many roads.

Comment: Why is there a downvote to my answer. I believe that "scarce traffic" encapsulates the OPs statement correctly.

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but **scarce** has a different meaning: *insufficient for demand*. For example: "At the food hall, tables were scarce", or "at the supermarket, toilet paper was scarce". In other words, people want (this thing) but there are not many of them. People don't usually "want" more traffic.

Comment: My apologies for not leaving a comment. I downvoted because the OP is asking about the density of traffic on a road, not the population density in a region. Your answer doesn't show how the word "scarce" applies to the OP's question

Comment: Ok just to be clear, I wanted to provide a more general explanation of the word while writing the answer. I have updated the answer to suit to OPs question a little more.

Answer (score -1):

You could say that the road is "deserted", or "desolate".

Comment: Welcome to English Language Learners! While this may be correct, we like our answers to be backed up by references. You can [edit] your answer to include one (e.g. an online dictionary). See the Help Center article [answer].